# Wordpress like Database structure pros and cons (Meta Key -> Value)

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am using Wordpress Like Database structure(https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description) to store values as meta key and value. After few days of records/entries, The meta table is increasing in size . So, I am taking expert advise if its a good idea to continue with this database structure . What are pros and cons for such database schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for pro:
you get to keep a simple structure and you could handle data much simpler.

for cons:
in the long run number of data may increase depending on the type of app your maintaining if you constantly add more and more post and each post may have a number of meta connected to it you may eventually feel a bit of impact on the loading time because to display a post you need to query each meta connected to it.

if you can implement a good caching you may do so to minimize your app for a need to keep on querying from the database to improve loading time or periodically run a maintenance command especially for the table that maintains the meta values to ensure optimal performance.

Comment: Thanks Christopher. What would you recommend for caching ?

Comment: I knew 3 object caching you apc, redis and memcache you may chose one of this 3 depending on what you really need.